# React - Iterate through text in an array and concat with old value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

I need to iterate through text in an array and concat with old value, like a person typing.

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-fermi-85xhr?file=/src/App.tsx):

```
  const [text] = useState(["123", "456", "789"]);
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState("000");

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
    console.log(current);
  }, [current]);

  const run = () => {
    text.map(t => setCurrent(t));
  };
```

But `current` jump from `'000'` to `'789'` value.

Comment: State changes are batched, so it's likely that after batching and executing them, the first ones get overwritten and only last state change prints. Whatever it is you're trying to do at a high level, this almost certainly isn't React way to do it. Some more context might help.

Comment: what do you mean by concat? do you want your final result to look like "123456789"?

Comment: Ever that a key is pressed the key is stored in an array, some time after i want to run all pressed keys and show in my text component, like the user was typing again.

@Naresh yes!

Comment: have you tried `text.join('')`

Comment: I need create a `<img/>` of all text steps when a trigger is called. Sorry, my example maybe was confusing. Please see this [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-morning-bqorn)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const text = ["123", "456", "789"];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState("000");

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
    console.log(current);
  }, [current]);

  const run = () => {
    var temp = ""
    text.map(t => temp+=t);
    setCurrent(temp)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{current}</h1>
      <button onClick={run}>UPDATE TEXT</button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shadow-bmqnq?file=/src/App.tsx:0-558)

Comment: Sorry, my initial example was confusing, please see my last comment.